# getting null return value from function

Tags: android, function, return-value

I have two class one is for api call. and other is for fetching value for api class. Returning value is null from function. how i get value from return value result.
here is function class :-

```
 Jsondeletenote js = new Jsondeletenote(context);
        String retn =    js.deletsubmitData();

        Log.d("calllllllllll render", "helo"+retn);
        // retn value coming null
```

here is api class

```
  public String deletsubmitData() {

        try {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        Log.d("looper", "-->>>>");
                        try {
                            isAuthorized = isAuthenticated();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception ==> ", e.toString());  
                        }
                        MHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    if(isAuthorized){
                                        if(AuthenticationResultJSONObject!=null){
                                             Day1 = AuthenticationResultJSONObject.getString("Day");
                                            String Tomorrow = AuthenticationResultJSONObject.getString("Tomorrow");
                                            String Week = AuthenticationResultJSONObject.getString("Week");

                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Loing unsuccessfull, please try again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } 
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("Exception 146==> ", e.toString());  
                                } 
                                finally 
                                {
                                    //dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception 153==> ", e.toString());  
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception 159==> ", e.toString());  
        }
        return Day1;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() 
    {
        isAuthorized = false;

        final String url="www.abcd.com";

        try {


                AuthenticationResultJSONObject = new JSONObject(doFetchDataFromWebService_Simple_OnlyJSONResponse(url));    

                Log.v("Online", "User json array    ===  "+AuthenticationResultJSONObject);  
    else
            {
                MHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please check your internet connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }*/
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            e.getMessage();
        }
        finally{
            if(AuthenticationResultJSONObject!=null){
                isAuthorized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isAuthorized=false;
            }
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all over the place. I suggest you rewrite it..

long story short you do an async work in a deferent thread, which means the return value of "deletsubmitData" will return immediately with null while the thread might be (and probably is) still working.

What you should do is change the method to return void and add a callback to the methods parameters. on the end of the thread's operations invoke the callback.

**EDIT:**
Create an interface with a method in it. then pass a new instance object from that interface as a parameter, which invokes the method.

Something like this:

Creation of interface:

```
public interface IExampleCallBack
{
    void onFinish(String result);
}
```

Creation of instance and pass as parameter:

```
IExampleCallBack callback = new IExampleCallBack(
{
    @Override
    public void onFinish(String result)
    {
        //do whatever you want with result.
    }
};
js.deletsubmitData(callback);
```

invoke of interface method in result:

```
public void deletsubmitData(IExampleCallBack callback)
{
    //your code inside the thread...
    //finish thread operation like so
    String resultExample = "finished";
    if (callback != null)
    {
        callback.onFinish(resultExample);
    }
}
```

**Note that if the callback parameter is null you will never get a callback from the thread, because of the null check. but it is better then having your application crashing.**

Good luck.

Comment: can you have me some explanation with code? how to apply callback methods?